# Replace text within brackets with thus-named variable in PHP

Tags: php, regex, string, replace

I want to replace all strings in square brackets (`[]`) with a randomly chosen item from an array that's named that string.

It's very similar to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10973958/php-str-replace-to-replace-need-with-random-replacement-from-array), but with a twist, in that I want to replace different brackets' contents with strings from arrays named that.

**An example should make this a bit clearer.**

So say I've got the string

```
"This is a very [adjective] [noun], and this is a [adjective] [noun]."
```

And the variables:

```
$adjective = array("big","small","good","bad");
$noun      = array("house","dog","car");
```

And we want it to return `"This is a very big house, and this is a good dog."` or whatever, by choosing randomly. That is, I want to write a PHP function that will replace each `[string]` with a randomly chosen item from the array named `$string`. For now it doesn't matter if by randomly choosing it ends up repeating choices, but it must make a fresh choice for each `[]` item.

I hope I've explained this clearly. If you get what I'm trying to achieve and can think of a better way to do it I'd be very grateful.

Comment: This should be pretty trivial. What have you tried till now ?

Comment: to remove repeats: pass the function a reference to the global word list, randomise the order and pop one off the end (reducing the number by one) and put in into the used list. If the original list is empty, set it to the used list to replenish it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Algorithm

1. Match for this regex: `(\[.*?\])`
2. For each match group pick an item from the related array.
3. Replace in string by order.

### Implementation

```
$string    = "This is a very [adjective] [noun], and this is a [adjective] [noun].";
$adjective = array("big","small","good","bad");
$noun      = array("house","dog","car");

// find matches against the regex and replaces them the callback function.
$result    = preg_replace_callback(

                 // Matches parts to be replaced: '[adjective]', '[noun]'
                 '/(\[.*?\])/',

                 // Callback function. Use 'use()' or define arrays as 'global'
                 function($matches) use ($adjective, $noun) {

                     // Remove square brackets from the match
                     // then use it as variable name
                     $array = ${trim($matches[1],"[]")};

                     // Pick an item from the related array whichever.
                     return $array[array_rand($array)];
                 },

                 // Input string to search in.
                 $string
             );

print $result;
```

### Explanation

**[preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php)** function performs a regular expression search and replace using provided callback function.

- **First parameter** is regular expression to match (enclosed between slashes): `/(\[.*?\])/`
- **Second parameter** is callback function to call for each match. Takes the current match as parameter.

  - We have to use `use()` here to access the arrays from inside the function, or define the arrays as global: `global $adjective = ...`. Namely, we have to do one of the followings:

    **a)** Define arrays as `global`:

    ```
      ...
      global $adjective = array("big","small","good","bad");
      global $noun      = array("house","dog","car");
      ...
      function($matches) {
      ...
    ```

    **b)** Use `use`:

    ```
      ...
      $adjective = array("big","small","good","bad");
      $noun      = array("house","dog","car");
      ...
      function($matches) use ($adjective, $noun) {
      ...
    ```
  - First line of the callback function:

    - **trim**: Removes square brackets (`[]`) from the match using `trim` function.
    - **${}**: Creates a variable to use as array name with the match name. For example, if the `$match` is `[noun]` then `trim($matches[1],"[]")` returns `noun` (without brackets) and `${noun}` becomes the array name: `$noun`. For more information on the topic, see **[variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)**.
  - Second line randomly picks an index number available for the `$array` and then returns the element at this position.
- **Third parameter** is the input string.

Comment: What does it mean using `${}` in this line: `${trim($matches[1],"[]")}`?

Comment: It is [variable of variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php). Updating answer with detailed information.

Comment: Yea, smart solution. But if the array names change then the pattern names must be changed too, so [adjective] [noun] etc (just a notice).

Comment: Yes, I think OP wants exactly this solution. If this is not the case, then a mapping between array names and match names can be added easily.

Comment: I'd even go a bit more far and say: Because those are parameter  values, they should not be hard-encoded as variable names. Sure this is no difference for the outcome, just for the approach.

Comment: So this is very close to doing what I'd like, thanks a lot. One issue though, is that there'll likely be hundreds of these variables. Is the only way to call of them within the function?

It'll be called iteratively, so some of the arrays might e.g. have the options "a house","a [adjective] house", and the script will comb back through again to replace these.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Right so, I'm trying to set this up so that I can just set all the arrays first and not clog up that function with them. I'm trying to do something along the lines of this in the function you gave:

// Remove square brackets from the match
// then use it as variable name
$array = $GLOBALS[{trim($matches[1],"[]")}];

But that throws an error. Any ideas?

Comment: @HughGrigg: I clarified what I meant and gave details. Please, see the answer again.

Answer (score 1):

The code below will do the work:

```
$string = "This is a very [adjective] [noun], and this is a [adjective] [noun]."

function replace_word ( $matches )
{
    $replaces = array(
        '[adjective]'  =>  array("big", "small", "good", "bad"),
        '[noun]'  =>  array("house", "dog", "car")
    );

    return $replaces[$matches[0]][array_rand($replaces[ $matches[0] ])];
}

echo preg_replace_callback("(\[.*?\])", "replace_word", $string);
```

First, we regular expression match on the `[something]` parts of the word, and call the `replace_word()` callback function on it with [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php). This function has an internal `$replaces` two dimension deep array defined inside, each row defined in a `[word type] => array('rep1', 'rep2', ...)` format.

The tricky and a bit obfuscated line is the `return $replaces[$matches[0]][array_rand($replaces[ $matches[0] ])];`. If I chunk it down a bit, it'll be a lot more parsable for you:

```
$random = array_rand( $replaces[ $matches[0] ] );
```

`$matches[0]` is the word type, this is the key in the `$replaces` array we are searching for. This was found by regular expression in the original string. [`array_rand()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) basically selects one element of the array, and returns its **numerical index**. So `$random` right now is an integer somewhere between `0` and the `(number of elements - 1)` of the array containing the replaces.

```
return $replaces[ $matches[0] ][$random];
```

This will return the `$random`th element from the replace array. In the code snippet, these two lines are put together into one line.

### Showing one element only once

If you want disjunct elements (no two adjective or noun repeated twice), then you will need to do another trick. We will set the `$replaces` array to be defined not inside the `replace_word()` function, but outside it.

```
$GLOBALS['replaces'] = array(
    '[adjective]'  =>  array("big", "small", "good", "bad"),
    '[noun]'  =>  array("house", "dog", "car")
);
```

Inside the function, we will set the local `$replaces` variable to be a reference to the newly set array, with calling `$replaces = &$GLOBALS['replaces'];`. (The `&` operator sets it a **reference**, so everything we do with `$replaces` (remove and add elements, for example) modifies the original array too. Without it, it would only be a copy.)

And before arriving on the `return` line, we call [`unset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) on the currently to-be-returned key.

```
unset($replaces[$matches[0]][array_rand($replaces[ $matches[0] ])]);
```

The function put together now looks like this:

```
function replace_word ( $matches )
{
    $replaces = &$GLOBALS['replaces'];
    unset($replaces[$matches[0]][array_rand($replaces[ $matches[0] ])]);

    return $replaces[$matches[0]][array_rand($replaces[ $matches[0] ])];
}
```

And because `$replaces` is a reference to the global, the `unset()` updates the original array too. The next calling of `replace_word()` will not find the same replace again.

#### Be careful with the size of the array!

Strings containing more replace variables than the amount of replace values present will throw an *Undefined index* `E_NOTICE`. The following string won't work:

```
$string = "This is a very [adjective] [noun], and this is a [adjective] [noun]. This is also an [adjective] [noun] with an [adjective] [noun].";
```

One of the outputs look like the following, showing that we ran out of possible replaces:

> This is a very big house, and this is a big house. This is also an small  with an  .

Answer (score 1):

Another good (easier) method of doing this (not my solution)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15773754/2183699

Using a foreach to check on which variables you want to replace and replacing them with

```
str_replace();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use preg_match and str_replace function to achive this goal.

- First find the matches using preg_match function and then create search & replace array from the result.
- Call str_replace function by passing the previous arrays as parameters.

Answer (score 0):

This is my minor update to mmdemirbas' answer above. It lets you set the variables outside of the function (i.e. use globals, as said).

```
$result    = preg_replace_callback(

                 // Matches parts to be replaced: '[adjective]', '[noun]'
                 '/(\[.*?\])/',

                 // Callback function. Use 'use()' or define arrays as 'global'
                 function($matches) use ($adjective, $noun) {

                     // Remove square brackets from the match
                     // then use it as variable name
                    $arrayname = trim($matches[1],"[]");
                    $array = $GLOBALS[$arrayname];

                     // Pick an item from the related array whichever.
                     return $array[array_rand($array)];
                 },

                 // Input string to search in.
                 $string
             );

print $result;
```

Comment: I also have a little question, though. Would it be possible to prevent the same item being used twice by unsetting it from the array when it gets used? I'm trying to do it with this, inserted just before "Input string to search in.":

    unset($GLOBALS[$arrayname[$item]]);

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work. As far as I can tell it has no effect?