# How change (replace) element in text?

Tags: php, replace

Good day.

We have code:

```
function testfunc($text){
 return $text;
}


$text = "Simple text {testfunc(1)} and next simple text and we {testfunc(20)} are happy ";
// number in {testfunc()} only for example - it can be other number or text.
```

Tell me please how replace `{testfunc(1)}` on result function testfunc($num)?

*P.S.: In result need get next text:*

```
$text = "Simple text 1 and next simple text and we 20 are happy ";
```

Comment: why dont use this? `$text = "Simple text ".testfunc(1)." and next simple text and we ".testfunc(20)." are happy ";`

Comment: YOUR SOLUTION IS HERE 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15773349/replacing-placeholder-variables-in-a-string

Comment: @Babyy becouse need use replace

Comment: @jack thanks but we need use function

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$newText = preg_replace_callback("/\{testfunc\((\d+)\)\}/","testfunc",$text);
```

And you'll get array of matches in your "testfunc". For what you want, this code:

I think, it helps you.

```
<?php

function testfunc($text){
    return $text[1];
}


$text = "Simple text {testfunc(1)} and next simple text and we {testfunc(20)} are happy ";
$newText = preg_replace_callback("/\{testfunc\((\d+)\)\}/","testfunc",$text);

echo $text."\n";
echo $newText."\n";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work, using string concatenation:

`$text = "Simple text " . testfunc(1) . " and next simple text and we " .  testfunc(20) . " are happy ";`

Comment: not right becose me need replace(see answer please).

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$text = "Simple text ".testfunc(1)." and next simple text and we ".testfunc(20)." are happy ";
```

Comment: not right becose me need replace(see answer please).

Comment: A few words of explanation would make this example even better.

Answer (score 0):

As normal why not try with,

```
$text = "Simple text ".testfunc(1)." and next simple text and we ".testfunc(20)." are happy ";
```

Comment: not right becose me need replace(see answer please).

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
     $text = "Simple text ".testfunc(1)." and next simple text and we ".testfunc(20)." are
happy";
echo $text;
?>
```

Comment: not right becose me need replace(see answer please).

Comment: A few words of explanation would make this example even better.