# Cutting out a word with substr

Tags: php, string

In PHP i'm trying to cut out a specific word with the `substr` function.

The way I am doin this is:

- Check if the word actually exists in the string:

  ```
  $haystack = "/home/{i:id}/{s:aString}";
  $needle = "{i:id}";

  if ($position = strpos($haystack, $needle)) {...}
  ```
- Calculate the last character in the word by using `substr`

  ```
  $haystack = "/home/{i:id}/{s:aString}";
  $needle = "{i:id}";

  if ($position = strpos($haystack, $needle)) {
     $rpos = strpos($haystack, substr($needle, -1), $position);
     ...
  }
  ```
- Print out the word by using `substr` again

  ```
  $haystack = "/home/{i:id}/{s:aString}";
  $needle = "{i:id}";

  if ($position = strpos($haystack, $needle)) {
     $rpos = strpos($haystack, substr($needle, -1), $position);

     echo substr($haystack, $position, $rpos);
  }
  ```

When running this piece of code, it strips the whole word, but stops way to late, it also takes 5 characters of the remainder of the string.

How do I fix this substr so it will only take the word i'm looking for?

Comment: Do you want to remove the word? If so, you should use `str_replace()`?

Comment: @eskimo That's not what I want to achieve.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replacing Placeholder Variables in a String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15773349/replacing-placeholder-variables-in-a-string)

Comment: So what do you mean by cut out?

Comment: @eskimo Get the characters between the 2 length positions i specify

Comment: By the way, your condition `if ($position = strpos($haystack, $needle))` won't work for the cases when the placeholder is at the beginning of the string. You should use `if (($position = strpos($haystack, $needle)) !== false)`. Anyway you should use `str_replace` as it was suggested before.

Comment: Depending on what you're using this for you could use `explode("/",$string)` to break the string into an array by the "/" character

Comment: do you want remove strings between two positions  correct ?

Comment: @RaguSwaminathan Yeah

Answer (score 0):

I'm not having enough reputation so posting answer. Try this,

```
<?php
$sentence  = "I want to remove all the common words from this sentence because they are irrelevant";
$common_words = array("to ", "this ", "all ", "the ", "from ");

$newphrase = str_replace($common_words, "", $sentence);
echo "Actual Word : ".$sentence."\n\nNew Word : ".$newphrase;
?>
```

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: please have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php it might help to improve your answer.