# Replace placeholders with dynamic data in strings with php

Tags: php, regex

I've got strings that look like this: "[1] edited profile picture of [2]" - The numbers in brackets stand for ID's of users (saved in Database). What would be an efficient way to replace these numbers with data from the database in PHP? I should also mention, that there can be zero of these numbers as well as twenty of them in a string. Thanks in advance!

Comment: See [*Replacing Placeholder Variables in a String*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15773349/replacing-placeholder-variables-in-a-string).

Comment: Build an associative array with `'[n]'` as keys and use `strtr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the function [strtr](http://php.net/manual/de/function.strtr.php)

```
<?php
$string = '[1] edited profile picture of [2]';

$replaceArray = array('[1]' => 'Mark Zuckerberg', 
                      '[2]' => 'John doe');

$string = strtr($sting, $replaceArray);
echo $string;
?>
```

Gives you

```
Mark Zuckerberg edited profile picture of John doe
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much!