# Array difference if there are duplicates

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following text, which i need it to be changing dynamically depending on a pattern replacement: (Sorry poor text)

> I will be at the library (%tomorrow%), to (%borrow%) my favorite (%book%), then i will go to a ticket booking agency to (%book%) a ticket to wherever.

So i will parse it the following code:

```
preg_match_all('/\(%(.*?)%\)/i', $content, $matches);

if(empty($matches)) return [];

$placeholders = $matches[0];

$matchings    = $matches[1];

$temp =[];

foreach ($matchings as $matching) {
    $temp[] = [$matching];
}

$matchings = $temp;

$matches = [$placeholders, $matchings];


return $matches;
```

Which will generate the following:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => '(%tomorrow%)',
    1 => '(%borrow%)',
    2 => '(%book%)',
    3 => '(%book%)',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      0 => 'tomorrow',
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      0 => 'borrow',
    ),
    2 => 
    array (
      0 => 'book',
    ),
    3 => 
    array (
      0 => 'book',
    ),
  ),
)
```

As you notice, two arrays, one for patterns, and the other for alternatives, and i have two `book` words, each one has it's different meaning.

Then i store this result in DB, which i can extend alternatives, with other code. So when i update the alternatives, i have the following:

```
    array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => '(%tomorrow%)',
    1 => '(%borrow%)',
    2 => '(%book%)',
    3 => '(%book%)',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      0 => 'tomorrow',
      1 => 'the next day',
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      0 => 'borrow',
      1 => 'get',
    ),
    2 => 
    array (
      0 => 'book',
      1 => 'novel',
    ),
    3 => 
    array (
      0 => 'book',
      1 => 'buy',
    ),
  ),
)
```

Now i have alternatives, so i start the replacement, by searching the text (say: for `(%tomorrow%)`) if exists, i will get it's index from the first array and then get the array of alternatives form the second array by `(%tomorrow%)`'s index, then pick one randomly.

Say i latter needed to edit the text (e.g. a post) and converted the first `(%book%)` to be normal without using the pattern (will be a fixed text), so i need the second (%book%) to keep it's connection to the correct alternative's. (The verbs not the nouns)

Comment: you can compare the array keys using [array_diff_key](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-key.php)

Comment: No @Atmahadli the output array is completely reindexed.

Comment: ...and @Robo you answered before a complete question was formed.  This isn't a race.  Let's make good questions and good answers.

Comment: @mickmackusa i just use the normal `preg_match_all`. please refer to edits

Comment: @mickmackusa Sorry, Yes

Comment: reindex means that you are creating new array. @mickmackusa is right, we need the details how you did it. if you are using [array_unique](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) you still have the keys

Comment: @Atmahadli I am not re-indexing, i just parse the text after edits and get the new matches, so i need to check what is delete after the second parse

Comment: Is this an XY-problem?  _Why_ do you need to know the original position of deleted elements?

Comment: @mic - sorry, I was accidentally hit the enter

Comment: @mickmackusa I have added why i need this

Comment: @Moh I think your problem is in the reindexed array, if you did not do it, then you should find it.

Comment: @mickmackusa I have tried to explain what i want to accomplish, is it enough?

Comment: Well, I must say, it looks like you have made a problem for yourself by not using unique identifiers in you "madlibs" document.  Why not simplify everything and use numerated keywords: `book1` and `book2` or maybe `bookV` and `bookN`?  This way, much of the hassle is removed.

Comment: @mickmackusa mmm, So, no way but unique identifiers!

Comment: Look at how simple this can be: https://3v4l.org/O1FlY  ...https://stackoverflow.com/q/15773349/2943403

Comment: @mickmackusa Yes it is, i should consider this approach